# Render component in component dynamically

Tags: reactjs

My app has 2 components: Location and User.

The locations are rendered when the page is loaded. Some locations have users. These users are loaded via an ajax call after the locations are rendered.

I wonder how I can render (conditionally) the user inside a location when that user is assigned to a location.

```
<App>
 <location id="1" />
 <location id="2" />
 <Location id="3">
  <User loactionId="3">
  </User>
 </Location id="4">
</App>
```

Comment: What's the condition for rendering users? Is `location` different from `Location`? What does the `id` indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render Component dynamically using following example:

**Method 1:**

**Here is the Location Component:**

```
import React from "react";
import {User} from "./User";

export class Location extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{margin:20, padding:20, color: '#FFFFFF', background: '#368BC1'}}>
                This is Location Component {this.props.value}
                {
                    this.props.user? <User/> : " No User Component"
                }

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Here is the User Component:**

```
import React from "react";

export class User extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{background: '#A0CFEC', padding: 20, color:'#000000'}}>
                This is User Component
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**App Component:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {Location} from "./parent-child/Location";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Location user={true} value={1}/>
                <Location user={false} value={2}/>
                <Location user={true} value={3}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));

export default App;
```

**Method 2:**

You can replace location Component with below code. Here I used React.createElement method to create Component dynamically.

```
import React from "react";
import {User} from "./User";

export class Location extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{margin:20, padding:20, color: '#FFFFFF', background: '#368BC1'}}>
                This is Location Component {this.props.value}
                {
                    this.props.user? React.createElement(User, {propValue: 'Hello World'}, null) : " No User Component"
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```